# Redirect to VF page if duplicate user exists in SSO Authantication

Tags: apex, community, authentication

I have created a community and created an Auth. Provider for google and linkedIn. This SSO are working correctly.

If a user logins for first time user will get created which is fine. But if user logins with another gmail account whose first name and last name are same then he should be redirected to a VF page which displays him all duplicate users with respect to first name and last name.

Now user will select the a user if it exists from first or else none is selected then a new user will get created for him.

But can i redirect to VF page if duplicate users are found. I am trying to redirect to a simple page but it is not redirecting to VF page.

Note: I have given permission to page too..

```
global class AutocreatedRegHandler1470057425156 implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
    global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
       List<User> u = [select Id, Profile.Name from user where email = 'kale.swapnil.r@gmail.com' and Profile.Name = 'Customer Community User'];
       redirectUser();
       system.debug('###Set reditrect done');
       return u[0];
    }
    global PageReference redirectUser() {
        PageReference acctPage = Page.CommunityUserPage;
        acctPage.setRedirect(true);
        system.debug('###Set reditrect true');
        return acctPage;                
    }
    global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
      redirectUser();
    }
}
```